# Wordpress add_rewrite_rule second argument not working

Tags: rewrite-rules

I am trying to use add_rewrite_rule() to solve a pagination problem I am having. After a lot of research I know the answer. But it seems the second argument of add_rewrite_rule() is never working.

```
add_action( 'init', 'add_category_base_rewrite_rule' );
function add_category_base_rewrite_rule() {
  add_rewrite_rule(
    'publicacoes/(.+?)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$',
    'index.php?post_type=artigo&category_name=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]',
    'top' 
  );
}
```

I am using the plugin [Debug This](https://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-this/) to check the rewrite rules

[image]

As you can see the second argument doesn't match what I put in my function. And no matter what I do it doesn't work.

I know the function is being called because it put my rule on the top.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: did you flush rewrite rules after making changes?

Comment: Yes I did. I put flush_rewrite_rules(true); right before my code in functions php. And tried to do it manually as well. Didn't work

Comment: When you call flush_rewrite_rules, rules get rebuilt from whatever is currently added in that request, so you must add_rewrite_rule *before* a flush.

Comment: I tried this.... What happens is that I can see the rule going up in the list, probably because of the 'top' parameter. But the rewrite still doesn't change. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

on the rewrite flush, the rewrite rule created by the custom post type overwrite yours because the target is the same.

to avoid this, you can use this filter

```
const TAXONOMY_PUBLICACOES = "publicacoes";

add_filter(TAXONOMY_PUBLICACOES . "_rewrite_rules", function ($rules) {

    unset($rules["publicacoes/(.+?)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$"]);

    return $rules;

});
```

Comment: I tried putting this code before and after 'add_rewrite_rule'. What I noticed is the rule going up in the rules' list. But the rewrite value still doesn't change. Am I missing someting in the 'add_rewrite_rule' ?

Comment: I am not even sure if this filter is being called. I tried to echo something inside the function to test, but I couldn't see the return.

Comment: I manage to call the filter, using apply_filters. But when I var_dump($rules) inside the filter, it is returning NULL.

Comment: The filter doesn’t run on every request, only when rules are flushed and rebuilt.

Comment: Got it... But it still didn't work =/.... I can see the rule go up in the list. But the rewrite value doesn't update. Any other thoughts?